# How are does LESS plugin work in Play Framework?

Tags: deployment, playframework, less

When I heard about LESS, I originally thought that they're usually pre-processed into css files, so browsers just encounter CSS files, not LESS files.

However, using LESS plugin for [Play Framework](http://playframework.org/), I just saw that my Chrome browser actually reads and interprets LESS files. LESS is claimed to be supported in all major browsers. So, do modern websites just serve LESS files, or do they pre-compile them into CSS? How does the LESS plugin work in Play Framework? Does it inject a Javascript snippet that interprets them client side?

What's actually happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the [Lunatech LESS plugin](https://github.com/lunatech-labs/play-module-less) for Play! 1, it looks like it actually compiles the `less` files on the fly using [Asual LESS](http://www.asual.com/lesscss/) and then serves it statically. An excerpt:

```
/**
 * Get the CSS for this less file either from the cache, or compile it.
 */
public String get(File lessFile) {
    String cacheKey = "less_" + lessFile.getPath() + lastModifiedRecursive(lessFile);
    String css = Cache.get(cacheKey, String.class);
    if(css == null) {
        css = compile(lessFile);
        Cache.set(cacheKey, css);
    }
    return css;
}

protected String compile(File lessFile) {
    try {
        return lessEngine.compile(lessFile);
    } catch (LessException e) {
        return handleException(lessFile, e);
    }
}
```

Where `lessEngine` is a `com.asual.lesscss.LessEngine` instance.

Like others have pointed out, the more common ways of using LESS is to compile them yourself before serving content, or using the [lesscss](http://lesscss.org/) JavaScript plug-in to have the client compile them at runtime.

Comment: So the fact my browser sees actual LESS files (foo.less) doesn't mean it's interpreting less ... I see. I guess it still has `type="text/css"` even though it ends with a `.less`.

Answer (score 1):

LESS css is "~compiled" by a javascript library (and should be done on the server side for production use).
You can read more on their site:
http://lesscss.org/#-client-side-usage

Comment: But my Chrome seems to understand native LESS files. I'm using Play Framework LESS plugin - I've made the question be focused around Play ... I'm not sure if the answer is generic or not.

Comment: Chrome doesn't understand it without a JavaScript that handles the `.less` file.

Comment: @ceejayoz - so maybe I'm serving some JS for that and I don't even know it. Hmm.

Comment: @ripper234 Ok, thats the right answer :) but your orignal question was without the play framework

Answer (score 0):

Both are options. Play! 2.0 will have built-in support for compiling LESS on the server side (and also CoffeeScript).

Comment: So how does the LESS module work by default? I haven't done any tweaking or configuration except installing the module, and LESS files just started working ... so I'm left wondering how they work.

Comment: I don't have experience of the LESS module on Play! 1. It won't be a module at all under 2.0, it'll be built in.

Comment: The way we use it, not specific to play, is to use `lessc` to compile the LESS into CSS where we can see it. No confusion, no automation.

Comment: It seems your answer would be better as a comment ... you describe how you _would_ use LESS in Play 2, but I'm asking about a Play 1 module.